# Using one onchange javascript function for all div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple `<textarea>`, sometime they are blank and sometime they are filled with text.

I want to insert a simple text code such as "`<check>`" which will automatically change to a check (`\u2713`).

Presently, my code is like this:

```
<textarea name="1-S" onchange="check(this.value)">
   <check> //an input written by a user
</textarea>
<textarea name="1-NI" onchange="check(this.value)">
   <check> //an input written by a user
</textarea>
<textarea name="1-C" onchange="check(this.value)">
   <check> //an input written by a user
</textarea>

(This block of <textarea> gets repeated, but of course, with different name in each one.)

<script type="text/javascript">
    function check(str){
        var res = str.replace("<check>", "\u2713");
        ????
    }
</script>
```

The output will then replace `<check>` into actual check symbol (`\u2713`)

The challenge is, I don't want to have to add ID to every `<textarea>` and then write a script for each one. So is there a way for me to use this one script to apply to all `<textarea>`???

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the getElementsByTagName method to create an array of your text area tags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can bind an event handler to all elements of a type using jquery.

```
$('textarea').on('change', function() {  
    var text = $(this).val();

    if (text.match(/\<check\>/)) {        
        $(this).val(text.replace(/\<check\>/, "\u2713"));
    }  
});
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that you can remove your inline 'onchange' handlers from the html and consolidate your validation logic strictly to JavaScript.

To replace the actual textarea content you need to update the value of the textarea with the result of your String-replace regexp. `var text = $(this).val()` is just assigning the content of the textarea to the variable `text`, it's not a reference to the innerHTML portion of your textarea.

On a sidenote if you'd like to allow users to use shortcodes in a form, prefer square bracket syntax, e.g., `[check]`.

Comment: I tried this:

var text = $(this).val();
text.replace("<check>", "\u2713");

That didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery:

```
$("textarea").each(function(index, textarea) {
    // do replacement here
});
```

Note that you need to use [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) to put `<check>` into a textarea: `&lt;check&gt;`

Also, you can put a checkmark in without any Javascript like this: `&#x2713;`

Comment: How do I apply the replace() function inside of this??

Comment: textarea.value = textarea.value.replace("<check>", "&#x2713;");

Comment: That didn't do the trick. I'm guessing inside the function, the change is made, but I cannot figure out how to return that changes into the textarea?

Comment: Did you include the "textarea.value = ..." part at the beginning?  Calling replace() by itself will not do it - Javascript strings are immutable.